# Pascal: How to compare a complex data type? Comparison of records

Tags: comparison, record, pascal

Currently, the compilation fails. For each comparison of `node` types the same error message is shown: *Operator is not overloaded: "node" = "node"*. Platform: Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0-9.

```
type
    node = record
        key : integer;
        end;

var
    nde1 : node;
    nde2 : node;

begin

    nde1.key := 1;
    nde2.key := 2;

    if not(nde1 = nde1) then
        writeln('Wrong.');
    if nde1 = nde2 then
        writeln('Wrong.');

end.
```

Yes, the comparison of `nde1.key` and `nde1.key` as well as `nde1.key` and `nde2.key` works.

```
    if not(nde1.key = nde1.key) then
        writeln('Wrong.');
    if nde1.key = nde2.key then
        writeln('Wrong.');
```

This alternative approach works, but is a workaround: Compares the memory addresses via `@`.

```
    if not(@nde1 = @nde1) then
        writeln('Wrong.');
    if @nde1 = @nde2 then
        writeln('Wrong.');
```

Example of application: Implementation of a linked list by typing a node which points to another node, if not being isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different types of comparison:

- Is `node1` exactly the same object as `node2`? In this case, use the `@` operator, it is like `ReferenceEquals()` and friend in modern languages.
- Do `node1` and `node2` contain the same data (independent of if they are the same object)? In this case use operator overloading: `operator = (node1, node2: node) res: boolean; ...`

Comment: (@ would be a conversion to a reference, not the equals operation itself. That is the =, which is implemented/overloaded for pointers/references)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Sorry, I don't really understand: IIUC, converting to a reference, then comparing the references does check, if 2 objects are the same

Comment: But that is not what you are saying in the post. You suggest @ is like the reference comparison in "modern" languages.  The @ is the conversion, a simple "=", old fashioned as it is, is the comparison.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort ... ofcourse, but he has that code already in the Question, so why should I need to explain it any further?